# Can i ask about oracle enqueue lock mechanism?

Tags: oracle

Question: What happens if Session D attempts to acquire a Shared mode lock between steps 3 and 4?

Enqueue Lock Operating Mechanism

1. Session A acquires the lock in Shared mode.
2. Session B attempts to acquire the lock in Shared mode. Since it is compatible with the lock currently held by Session A, it successfully acquires the lock. Now, both sessions are listed as owners of the lock.
3. Session C attempts to acquire the lock in Exclusive mode. There is no compatibility between Shared mode and Exclusive mode, so it registers itself in the wait list and waits.
4. When both sessions A and B release the lock, session C, which was waiting, becomes an owner of the lock in Exclusive mode.
5. If Session A attempts to acquire the lock again in Exclusive mode, it is not compatible with Exclusive mode, so it registers itself in the wait list and waits.
6. Similarly, when Session B attempts to acquire the lock again in Shared mode, it is not compatible with Exclusive mode, so it registers itself in the wait list and waits.
7. Since Enqueue Lock ensures a sequential order, when Session C releases the lock, Session A is the first to acquire the lock in Exclusive mode.

Answer (score -3):

Of course! I can provide information about Oracle enqueue lock mechanisms. In Oracle Database, enqueue locks are used to control access to various resources and ensure data integrity in a multi-user environment. These locks are essential for preventing conflicts and maintaining database consistency. Here's an overview of the Oracle enqueue lock mechanism:

Enqueue Types:

DML Locks: Used for controlling concurrent access to data. Examples include row-level locks, table locks, and partition locks.
Distributed Locks: Used in distributed database environments to coordinate transactions across multiple databases.
Library Cache Locks: Protect shared SQL and PL/SQL objects stored in the library cache.
Latches: Lightweight locks used for protecting data structures in memory, like buffers in the buffer cache.
Mutexes: Mutual exclusion locks used for synchronizing access to various resources.
Enqueue Resources:

Enqueue locks are associated with specific resources in the database, such as tables, rows, and internal structures.
Each enqueue resource has a unique name, and Oracle manages these locks through the database's shared memory structures.
Lock Modes:

Enqueue locks can be acquired in different modes, such as shared (S), exclusive (X), or null (N) mode.
Shared locks allow multiple sessions to read the resource simultaneously.
Exclusive locks grant exclusive access to a single session for modification.
Enqueue Wait Events:

When a session requests a lock and another session holds an incompatible lock on the same resource, the requesting session enters a wait state.
Oracle records enqueue-related wait events in the V$SESSION_WAIT view, making it possible to identify and troubleshoot lock contention issues.
Deadlocks:

Deadlocks can occur when two or more sessions are waiting for locks held by each other, causing them to be stuck.
Oracle's deadlock detection mechanism identifies these situations and resolves them by automatically rolling back one of the conflicting transactions.
Monitoring and Tuning:

DBAs can monitor enqueue lock activity using various database views, such as V$LOCK, V$SESSION, and DBA_BLOCKERS/DBA_WAITERS.
Tuning SQL queries, optimizing indexing, and properly designing applications can help minimize lock contention issues and improve database performance.
Concurrency Control:

Enqueue locks play a crucial role in maintaining data consistency and preventing data corruption in a multi-user environment.
They ensure that concurrent transactions do not interfere with each other when accessing shared resources.

Comment: Then,, What happens if Session D attempts to acquire a Shared mode lock between steps 3 and 4?

Comment: This looks like an AI (e.g. ChatGPT) generated answer. Such answers are banned here on SO.